# Looking for suitable word for doing errand jobs / petty jobs

Tags: american-english

I am looking for a suitable word for doing errand / petty jobs. Clerk is not the right word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***minion***

> a ​person who is not ​important and who has to do what another ​person
>   of ​higher ​rank ​orders them to do:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minion

Answer (score 6):

**[Gofer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gofer)**

> A person who runs errands, especially on a film set or in an office; a dogsbody:

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: +1 I added a textual cite. This is our preferred form (text and link) so that readers have a quick indication of the quality of the cite.

Comment: Thank you .. i never heard of the word : dogsbody ... which is perfect

Answer (score 2):

***[Errand boy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/errand+boy)***:

> - (Professions) (in Britain, esp formerly) a boy employed by a shopkeeper to deliver goods and run other errands

(Collins Dictionary)

also

***[guy Friday](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/guy-friday)***:

> - a man who acts as a general assistant in a business office or to an executive and has a wide variety of especially secretarial and clerical duties.

Comment: and girl Friday

Answer (score 1):

A go-fer is an assistant who's job title derives from the responsibilty of getting coffee for the boss and doing other menial tasks.

"Errand boy" is the derisive title that Kurtz gives Willard in Apocalypse Now: "You're an errand boy, sent by grocery clerks, to collect a bill."

Also: peon, grunt (as in grunt work)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term ***factotum*** or ***general factotum***.

Oxford Dictionaries Online says:

> ...an employee who does all kind of work. ORIGIN - mid 16th century
>   (originally in the phrases *dominum* (or *magister factotum*),
>   translating roughly as "master of everything", and *Johannes factotum*
>   "John do-it-all" or "Jack of all trades": from medieval Latin, from
>   Latin *fac!* "do!" (imperative of *facere*) + *totum* "the whole
>   thing" (neuter of *totus*).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, you might consider

***office boy***

> : a person, traditionally a boy, employed in an office to run errands, do odd jobs, etc. [1840–50]
>
> [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/office+boy)
>
> *An Office Boy job responsibilities fall into administrative assistants or secretaries. Their duties vary depending on the business office environment. An office boy position is an entry-level one, often filled by interns or recent graduates. Office boys perform various basic administrative duties, such as serving beverages to the guests or staff, handling electronic files and papers, greeting visitors and so on.*
>
> [Sample Job Descriptions](http://www.samplejobdescriptions.org/office-boy-job-description.html)

***bellhop***

> :  a hotel or club employee who escorts guests to rooms, assists them with luggage, and runs errands
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellhop)

***lackey***

> : someone who does menial tasks or runs errands for another
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lackey)

Answer (score 0):

I think "personal assistant" is the preferred term in Corporate America.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/personal-assistant?s=t

Flunky is another good one, if you're trying to be humorous.